# Removing Github from Xcode project

Tags: xcode, github

I had an Xcode project and iPhone app that I coped the folder and project and pasted and renamed because I want to reskin the app as a different app. I had the origional app hooked up to a GitHub repo.  Im worried that the app I copied may be hooked up to the same repo and want to remove it from github completely.

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a .git folder in root folder. Just delete that.

Comment: I marked the answer correct and thanks so much. Is there an easy way to find this folder I can't seem to find it?

Comment: cd to the project directory and do `ls -a` in terminal. It is a hidden folder on Mac OS filesystem or finder.

Comment: Didn't make any difference for me.